# Count with join in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My query is:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetCount] 
@PID INT,
@IA BIT=null
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT count(*) from [dbo].[Ps] 
 WHERE  P.PID= @PID
 FROM Ps p inner join PMU pm ON p.PSID=pm.PSID 
 AND pm.PID=@PID and pm.IA=@IA 
END
```

But i got a syntax error.Plz help to find my mistake.Thanks.

Comment: What's the details of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetCount] 
@PID INT,
@IA BIT=null
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT count(*) 
 FROM Ps p 
      INNER JOIN PMU pm ON p.PSID=pm.PSID 
                           AND pm.PID=@PID 
                           AND pm.IA=@IA 
 WHERE  P.PID= @PID
END
```

Comment: i run this query and i got a error `Incorrect syntax near '@PID'.`.Any suggestion.

Comment: i got it `where p.PID =  Pm.PID`.Its solve the problem.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the format of a `SELECT` statement for sql:

```
SELECT <ColumnName1, ColumnName2...>
FROM <TableName1, TableName2...>
WHERE <Conditions...>
ORDER BY <ColumnName1...>
```

So, if I re-write your code which would be as below:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetCount] 
@PID INT,
@IA BIT = null
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM Ps p INNER JOIN PMU pm ON p.PSID = pm.PSID 
          AND pm.PID=@PID AND pm.IA=@IA 
  WHERE  P.PID= @PID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This : [u can also try renaming the parameters]

> CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetCount]  @PID INT, @IA BIT=null AS BEGIN  SELECT
>   count(*) from [dbo].[Ps]   WHERE  P.PID= @PID  FROM Ps p inner join
>   PMU pm Where p.PSID=pm.PSID   AND pm.PID=@PID and pm.IA=@IA  END